# Android place activity on another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities in my app, **FirstActivity** and **SecondActivity**. **FirstActivity** accesses information from the internet so it takes a few seconds to load initially. I'd like to be able to open **SecondActivity** and then easily go back to **FirstActivity** without reloading it.

One of the thoughts I had on how best to accomplish this would be to open **SecondActivity** on top of **FirstActivity**, and then remove **SecondActivity**, when the user wishes to go back to **FirstActivity**. That way **FirstActivity** doesn't have to reload because it was loaded the whole time, merely hidden behind **SecondActivity**.

However I'm not really sure how to best accomplish this task. I couldn't figure out how to open an activity on top of another activity. Any help on how best to do this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that is the best way to go about it? What exactly are you trying to do? Fragment are likely a good start.

Answer (score 0):

> FirstActivity accesses information from the internet so it takes a few seconds to load initially. I'd like to be able to open SecondActivity and then easily go back to FirstActivity without reloading it.

I recommend that you start with the 2nd activity directly, and from there you begin an async task to download whatever you need from the internet. When the async task is done, you simply switch to the first activity, which uses the things you downloaded. If you have few things to pass over, consider putting the downloaded info as an extra to the activity switch intent.

Alternatively, look into fragments:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Have your two current activities be two fragments. For the main activity, set the 2nd fragment as active at the start of the app. When the download is finished, switch to the 1st fragment.

Comment: The only problem is I don't want the 2nd activity to be opened until the 1st activity has initially loaded. In order to get to the 2nd activity, you have to go through the 1st one. What I'd like to be able to do is close the 2nd activity after it's been opened without having to reload the 1st activity.

Comment: Fragments are your solution then.